# Deleting sql table and triggers connected to this table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm working with SQL Server. What exactly happens with triggers connected to some table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
ON MyTable FOR UPDATE AS ...
```

when we delete this table with **DROP TABLE** command?

I did some research and contrary to my expectations they seem to still exist  after the table is dropped which can be checked by

```
select * from sys.objects where type_desc='SQL_TRIGGER'
```

What if I create this table again? Will they start working again?

And is there any option to delete table together with the triggers?

Comment: Unable to reproduce on SQL Server 2008. Dropping the table causes your final query to return 0 rows on my test box. Can you come up with a short but complete script that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: When you run `sp_configure`, what is the `run_value` for `allow updates`?

Answer (score 0):

Which version do you have? For [SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx) it explicitly says that dropping a table

> ...Removes...all data, indexes,
>   **triggers**, constraints, and permission specifications for those tables

The same is true for [SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). You cannot drop a table if it is referenced by a foreign key restraint, so are you sure it was really removed?